# How to separate @RenderBody() into two parts

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im using ASP.NET Core 2.2. The problem that I have is I don't know where to use
`@RenderBody()` in my *_Layout* page. This is representation of what I want to do:
[image]

The green parts should come from *_Layout* and white parts coming from *HomePage.cshtml*. My *HomePage* consists of two parts  a slider and a list of content below it.This is what I tried, but it doesn't meet my need because i can't put slider in it.

this is **_Layout**

```
<html>
   <body>
       <main>
       <header></header>
       <div class="left-col">
       <div class="content">@RenderBody()</div>
       <div class="right-col">
       <footer></footer>
    </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: read up on sections https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2#specifying-a-layout

Comment: @Nkosi I'm not begionner dude. I know what is _layout and how to specify it. The problem is my _HomePage_ consists of two parts. where one part should come before _.left-col_  and another part should come after _.left-col_

Comment: I never implied you were a beginner. I was saying you can achieve what you want using sections. Check the section topic link in my previous comment.

Comment: @Then post ur answer pls. Cause I didn't find any helpful/related point in the link that you have provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a section in the layout to render the desired content

**HomePage.cshtml**

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@section Slider {

   <div>My HomePage slider</div>

}

<p>My HomePage content</p>
```

The layout would check to see if the section exists and render it if it does

**_Layout.cshtml**

```html
<html>
   <body>
       <main>
       <header></header>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Slider")) {
       <div class="homepage-slider">
         @RenderSection("Slider", required: false)
       </div>
    }
       <div class="left-col">
       <div class="content">@RenderBody()</div>
       <div class="right-col">
       <footer></footer>
    </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

You would obviously have to specify what ever styling needed to position the section where desired.

Reference [Layout in ASP.NET Core: Sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2#sections)